# Octave Parallel Computing Toolbox

Tags: parallel-processing, octave

Can anyone who has successfully used the Octave Forge package "parallel" (latest version [2.2.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/parallel-2.2.0.tar.gz/download)) share some of their experience on how to use it?

For a start, I'd like to execute a for loop in parallel on a single computer, something similar to the following code in Matlab

```
matlabpool open 4;

for i = 1:n_pts
    % Execute something in parallel
end

matlabpool close;
```

I just installed the package but I cannot find any useful documentation on how to actually use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no "parallel for" in octave yet.

But if you need something calculated for each i, you can use the example "simple" I just created in
[Octave wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Parallel_package), replacing x_vector with 1:n_pts, and the function "fun" with yours.

Comment: Thanks! The examples will definitely work for me. However, I was unable to find the `parcellfun` and `pararrayfun` in the `parallel` package. I installed it using the `pkg` command in octave (`pkg install -forge parallel`).

Comment: They should definitely be there if you have the 2.2.0 version. Did you load the package ? (`pkg load parallel`)

Comment: You're right. I didn't load the package. They're there now. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. The instructions for pkg install and load have now been added to the wiki page.